# Can't kill user process

Tags: linux, process, kill

On a Linux system it seems I can't kill my process I just started. `ps -ax` output:

```
6731 pts/1    DLl    0:06 ./main
```

I tried

```
kill -9 6731
```

but it just stays there. I don't have root access. What are my options?

Comment: You sure the process belongs to you and it is still running and not a zombie?

Comment: Yes, belongs to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's blocked on disk IO (uninterruptible sleep).  Is it on an NFS volume? It will be killed once it's unblocked.

If it is doing disk IO on an NFS volume and that volume is unreachable then you normally can't kill it. If you mount the NFS with "intr" option then you should be able to signal the process (kill it). If it is not mounted that way now then you probably will have to reboot to clear it.  The best option is to just get the NFS server to come back and service the request.

Comment: It is on NFS volume. I didn't block it. Any options?

Comment: @Frank: Here "blocked" means "waiting for some function to finish", in this case it tried to read or write a file over NFS, but the NFS server might be down or something. If the filesystem has been mounted with `nointr`, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Maybe bringing the network interface down and back up will unblock the NFS operation and let the process die.